# Display console output within NSView

Tags: swift, xcode

In swift, I am trying to basically have all of my `print()` statements display in an NSView. I am new to Swift so I am not sure the best method to do so. I couldn't imagine creating multiple labels, as there is no telling how often the console text will update.

The reason I am doing this is because I want my macOS app to show the user what methods are currently running, and what they are doing. Typically, in console applications, you can simply use `print()` to tell the user what is happening within the program, however, now that I am experimenting with GUI application, I would like to display that text within an NSView.

Comment: You are probably looking for `NSTextView`

Comment: Thank you, @vadian - That's exactly what I needed. I feel like that was way too obvious. o.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vadian, NSTextView is what I was looking for.

**Create the NSTextView**

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTerminal: NSTextField!
```

**Output Console Text**

```
myTerminal.stringValue = "Hello World" // or any other string.
```